# Android Studio 2.1 preview failing to find target with hash string 'android-N'

Tags: android

today i have update A.S. to 2.1 preview
and have error:

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-N' in: D:\android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ua.pensia.pensioncalculator"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 'N'
    versionCode 10
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

and installed SDK list

[image: installed sdk list]

directory `D:\android\sdk\build-tools\` have 2 folders:

```
23.0.2   (81 Mb)
24.0.0-preview  (92 Mb)
```

directory `D:\android\sdk\platforms\` have 9 folders:

```
android-15
android-16
android-17
android-18
android-19
android-20
android-21
android-22
android-23   (105 Mb)
android-N    (122 Mb)
```

BUT! directory `D:\android\sdk\sources` have only 8 folders!!! (without android-N)

maybe it is that problem?

changing `compileSdkVersion 'android-N'` to `compileSdkVersion 'N'` make no sense
error just modified to:

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'N' in: D:\android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me, not entirely sure what's the difference:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion '24rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        ...
    }
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ...
}
```

And in the top-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-alpha1'
    }    
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: error still shows. do you have folder `...\sdk\sources\android-N` ?

Comment: @НикакНикакая - No, I have no such folder. This is not surprising - other API version have a "sources" package that you can download; this one doesn't. Is there anything else you'd like me to check?

Answer (score 1):

```
model {
    android {
       compileSdkVersion 24
       buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

on my `build.gradle` now makes the build work on the Android SDK 24 preview 4, tested on the Vulkan examples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials/pull/12

The API for this preview seems to be final, so I think this is what code should look like after the release.

Answer (score 0):

After you've updated Android Studio to the latest version (available on canary channel), make sure that you installed the latest SDK and got Java 8 JDK and JRE.

Your `build.gradle` looks ok though.

Please refer to the [official set up guide](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I updated the SDK Manager , closed and re opened Android Studio but it did not work. Then I modified the build.gradle file and synced again. This worked. The changes are as below:

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inauth.spoofdetection"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }`